# App quit after throwing an error on console - win death . !

Tags: android

HI All.

I m working on a app that is exactly like a radio when i start a channel and go to the home screen radio is running successfully but some time it throws an error and crash and quit the application i got the error on my console .What kind of this error is and how can we remove this error.

INFO/WindowManager(90): WIN DEATH: Window{448521c0 com.cls.radio.app.screen/com.cls.radio.app.screen.StationListScreen paused=false}

Any code or idea will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: looks like android is killing your app by way of garbage cleaning..

Answer (score 0):

That's when the app (alone or together with others running) is using too much resources.